# Windows 11 Search doesn't show settings anymore after User folder name change

Tags: windows-11, windows-search

I recently changed the name of my user folder in Windows 11 and edited the registry to correct all the filepaths I could edit to point to the new directory, as well as changing the ProfileImagePath. However, it appears that somehow this broke Windows 11 Search, as it will now no longer display settings options when searching (e.g. searching Path on another acocunt on the same computer gives the Edit Environment Variables option, but on the changed account, it just shows nothing. Is there a way I can fix this or at least reset Windows Search so that it can find those options again? Thanks!

Comment: You should undo your changes.  Then follow these instructions  https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-change-account-name-on-windows-11

Comment: Try [rebuilding the Search](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-rebuild-windows-search-index-fix-problems/) index completely.

Comment: Have already tried rebuilding the search index unfortunately

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to change the USER folder name. Back up important stuff from your profile, delete it, and make a new USER Account.

Answer (score 0):

On hindsight I definitely agree with some of the comments that its not a good idea to change the user folder name, it does cause quite a few problems that aren't that straightforward to fix. However, to fix the specific issue of Windows Search being broken, the only solution I've tried that works is to reinstall windows 11 in place, using a USB or CD. You can choose to keep your files and apps, and this will reinstall windows utilities including search.